# I cannot assign a variable with Python's falsy

Tags: python, pandas

I'm stuck. I want to assign a variable asset to a CSV file, if the file is absent, a second file is sought. 
I got this code but it seems not to work.

```
a = pd.read_csv('me.csv') or 'report_generator.csv'
print(a)
```

Comment: It is not clear what your goal is. What is your input, and what is the expected result? What error are you getting? Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

try:
    df = pd.read_csv('one.csv')
except:
    df = pd.read_csv('two.csv')

print(df.head())
```

It would try to open 'one.csv', and if any error occurs (note that the error could be even if the csv exists but the data was corrupted), then it would open 'two.csv'.

**[EDITED]**

A more beautiful and safe solution would be checking whether the file exists explicitly:

```
import os.path as path

if path.exists('one.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv('one.csv')
elif path.exists('two.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv('two.csv')
else:
    print("Could not find csv")
```

Comment: I'm relieved. It was so simple yet I forgot this.. Thanks anyway.